# Trigger onSubmit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reactjs, submit

I have a component with a `form` where the `onSubmit` handler is set to `this.props.onSubmit`.

I'm trying to add some extra functionality to this form, I want it to submit after a pause (1000ms).

I can't seem to submit the form with jquery `$inputQuery.trigger('submit')` if I just call `.onSubmit()` the handler won't have the `event`.

```
  componentDidMount: function () {
    console.log('hi')
    var _this = this
    var dn = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputQuery)
    var $inputQuery = $(dn)
    $inputQuery.on('keyup', function () {
      console.log('bo')
      delay(function () {
        console.log('boook')
        // $inputQuery.trigger('submit') // doesn't work
        // $inputQuery.submit() // doesn't work
        _this.props.onSubmit()
      }, 1000)
    })
  },
```

How can I trigger a `onSubmit` event on a specific `ref` with react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3249) I learned that:

> ...jQuery doesn't trigger a real DOM event, but tries to find callbacks in its own internal event map...
>   — [bloodyowl](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3249#issuecomment-77814784)

To simulate / trigger an event use `React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate` which methods like `.click()` and `.submit()` and are supplied a `node`.

Which changes `componentDidMount` to this:

```
function () {
  var time = this.props.fireSubmitOnEntry
  if (this.props.fireSubmitOnEntry) {
    var inputNode = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputQuery)
    var formNode = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.form)
    var $input = $(inputNode)
    $input.on('keyup', function (e) {
      var code = e.which
      if (code === 13) return false
      delay(function () {
        React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.submit(formNode)
      }, time)
    })
  }
}
```

Just remember to use `var React = require('react/addons')` with `npm` to access `TestUtils`.

Comment: `import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';`

`ReactTestUtils.Simulate.submit(formNode)`